# Preg_Match data outside of square brackets

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string from *MySQL* and I want to get the data outside the square brackets.

Here are **my data**:

```
[USERNAME] User [OS INFO] Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 [MACHINE NAME] MACHINE-2[LANGUAGE_INFORMATION] 4.0.30319.1
```

How to **get this**:

```
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
```

**Tried by this**:

```
preg_match_all("/].*?\[/", $adat["INFORMATION"], $result_array);
```

After this **I get**:

```
 print_r( $result_array[0][1] );

 ] Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 [
```

How to get the data without the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets

```
preg_match_all("/](.*?)\[/", $adat["INFORMATION"], $result_array);
```

then,

```
print_r( $result_array[1][1] );
```

> Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1

Note the difference in print_r

Answer (score 0):

Try matching with braces like this

```
preg_match_all("/](.*?)\[/", $adat["INFORMATION"], $result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with brackets `()`

```
preg_match_all("/](.*?)\[/", $adat["INFORMATION"], $result_array);
```

As alternative, you can use [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function